# Recreating Google Homepage (html/css): Questions regarding positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a project on recreating the Google homepage with html and css. I am for the most part finished with the project, but I've noticed a few quirks that are irritating me. I've spent a great deal of time on each of these quirks, but can't get things to way I want them to look. These are the following quirks:

1. The icon in the top right-hand corner isn't inline with the rest of the text.
2. For some reason I can't center the buttons properly.
3. Not sure how to handle the white space surrounding the grey footer.

[JSFiddle of The Code](https://jsfiddle.net/theonlybrian/j2k9taj3/145/)

If you have any input on any of the above issues, I would forever be thankful!

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <ul class="navbar">
            <li class="navli"><a href="#"> +You </a>

            </li>
            <li class="navli"><a href="#">Gmail</a>

            </li>
            <li class="navli"><a href="#">Images</a>

            </li>
            <li class="navli" id="icon">
                <img src="http://bit.ly/1NHEwTW" height="auto" width="30" />
            </li>
            <li class="navli"><a href="#">theonlybrianlie@gmail.com</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="searchbar">
            <input type="text" id="search1" />
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <input class="button" id="googlesearch" value="Google Search" type="submit">
            <input class="button" id="secondbutton" value="I'm Feeling Lucky" type="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="leftfoot">
            <ul>
                <li class="lf"> <a href="#">Advertising</a>

                </li>
                <li class="lf"> <a href="#">Business</a>

                </li>
                <li class="lf"> <a href="#">About</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="rightfoot">
            <ul>
                <li class="rf"> <a href="#">Privacy</a>

                </li>
                <li class="rf"> <a href="#">Terms</a>

                </li>
                <li class="rf"> <a href="#">Settings</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.button {
font-family:Arial;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:bold;
display:inline;
height:30px;
border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
background:#f2f2f2;
padding-left: 10px;
}
body, html {
height:100%
}
#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position: relative;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.logo img {
display:block;
width: 269px;
height:95px;
margin:auto;
margin-top: 80px;
padding-top: 112px;
}
#header {
width:100%;
height:100px;
/*background-color:green*/
;
}
.navbar {
/*background-color: red;*/
float: right;
}
.navli {
display: inline-block;
font-family: Arial;
}
.navli a {
text-decoration:none;
color: #404040;
font-size: 13px;
padding-left: 15px;
}
.navli a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
}
#icon {
margin-top:10px;
padding-left:15px;
bottom:0;
position:relative;
}
.searchbar {
width:400px;
height:28px;
margin: auto;
display:block;
/*background-color:red;*/
padding-top:10px;
}
#search1 {
width:400px;
height:28px;
margin: auto;
}
#buttons {
display:block;
/*background-color:blue;*/
height: 22px;
width:250px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
}
#footer {
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
height:60px;
width:100%;
background-color:#f2f2f2;
clear:both;
display:block;
border-top: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
}
#leftfoot {
width:300px;
left:0;
/*background-color:blue;*/
display: inline-block;
}
.lf {
display: inline-block;
}
.lf a {
text-decoration:none;
color: #404040;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: Arial;
padding-left: 15px;
}
.lf a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
#rightfoot {
width:250px;
float:right;
/*background-color:blue;*/
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.rf {
display: inline-block;
margin:auto;
}
.rf a {
text-decoration:none;
color: #404040;
font-size: 13px;
padding-left: 15px;
font-family: Arial;
}
.rf a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: You've got three questions in your post. How will you go about selecting the right answer? Must an answer contain three answers? For future reference, you probably should have broken this down into three separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your top right icon not inline with the rest of the menu, i would alter the CSS like this

```
.navli {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

#icon {
  /* margin-top: 10px; */
  padding-left: 15px;
  /* bottom: 0; */
  /* position: relative; */
}
```

For your buttons not centering:

Add `text-align:center;` to `#buttons`

And for the white space on footer:

There's a margin on your `body`, so change your `body,html` to this:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the JSFiddle - [Full Screen Preview](http://fiddle.jshell.net/j2k9taj3/147/show/) - [JSFiddle View](https://jsfiddle.net/j2k9taj3/147/)

Comment: Fixed thanks to your help. Thanks incredibly for helping me out!

Answer (score -2):

I'll try to answer these as concisely as possible:

1- the heading is inline, and your icon is taller than the rest of the inline elements.  play with the margin and padding for your text elements there.

2- place your buttons in a div or section element of their own, and use text-align: center to center them on the page

3- add a class="container-fluid" to your footer element.